# Write to Snowflake VARIANT column from R

Tags: r, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am trying to load data to snowflake using the following code, but getting an error.

```
con <- DBI::dbConnect(
      drv    = odbc::odbc(), 
      driver = "SnowflakeDSIIDriver",
      server = "<>",
      authenticator = 'externalbrowser',
      warehouse = "<>",
      database = "<>",
      UID    = "<>", 
      role = "<>"
    )

DBI::dbAppendTable(con, name = DBI::Id(schema = "<>", table = "<>"), value = tmp[1:2,])
```

tmp was downloaded from Snowflake, the same table using RStudio:

````
```{sql connection=con, output.var = 'tmp'}
select top 10 * 
FROM <> 
```
````

The error seems to be stemming from a VARIANT column where I store a JSON string.

Error in new_result(connection@ptr, statement, immediate) :
nanodbc/nanodbc.cpp:1374: 22000: SQL compilation error:
Expression type does not match column data type, expecting VARIANT but got VARCHAR(2) for column FEATURES

Answer (score 0):

I had this once and it was an invalid JSON (missing brackets somewhere). Probably this helps.